# Rendering different components in AG Grid based on a given cell value

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Using Angular and AG Grid, say I have multiple Material components, such as a slider, a toggle and a dropdown. Now I want to render these components based on a certain value in another cell. So if a cell in column 1 has the value "1" in it I want this other cell in f.ex column 2 to render a checkbox, if the value is "2" I want to render a mat-select etc... How would one go about this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/cell-rendering/

Comment: Maybe I need to reiterate. I know how to render a custom component, the logic of how to get the value from another cell and render different component based on that value is hazy for me.